# multiple javaws instances using different proxy

Tags: linux, java

I tend to work with javaws applications. I also have to set different proxies for them (for each javaws application). Up until today, I was using one application at a time, and manually changing proxies in java Control Panel.

My proxy properties are stored in ~/.javaws/deployment/deployment.properties file.

I was wondering if it would be possible to start a javaws application which is using an other ~/.java directory, because this way I could run multiple javaws applications with different proxy settings at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing your `HOME` environment variable (in the specific javaws startup script) to point to different folder, probably one being a sub directory of your regular `/home/$USER`

Comment: i give it a try